# Entity framework where, order and group

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I'm using the following LINQ to select data from a table:

```
(from m in entity.Results
where m.Group == 0 ||
m.Group == 1
orderby m.Points descending
select m);
```

This gives me a result of all Users who are in Group 1 or 2. With that i can display the points they have. But this shows me the points they have in Group 1 and Group 2 separately.

How can i group them and display the total points they have? So instead of this (What i have now):

```
user1 - group1 - 10
user1 - group2 - 7
user2 - group1 - 7
user2 - group2 - 5
```

I want this:

```
user1 - total: 17
user2 - total: 12
```

How do i have to adjust my query to get a result set like that?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to group the users, then use `Sum` to calculate the `TotalPoints`:

```
from m in entity.Results
where m.Group == 0 || m.Group == 1
group m by m.User into g
let TotalPoints = g.Sum(m => m.Points)
orderby TotalPoints descending
select new { User = g.Key, Username = g.Key.Username, TotalPoints };
```

Comment: This seems to be working. But i'd also like to include the Username in the results. So in the **select new { ... }** part i tried to add this --- g.First().User.Username. But this doesn't seem to be working. Any idea how i can include the Username aswell?

Comment: @Vivendi You already selected the `User`, you don't need to change the query. Or you can do this `select new { User = g.Key, Username = g.Key.Username, TotalPoints };

Answer (score 22):

```
entity.Results
      .Where(m => m.Group == 0 || m.Group == 1)
      .GroupBy(m => m.UserID)
      .Select(m => new { User = m.Key, TotalPoints = m.Sum(v => v.Points) })
      .OrderByDescending(m => m.TotalPoints);
```

Answer (score 2):

Hi Vivendi use this(Please edit according to your requirement)

```
var q = (from h in entity.Results
group h by new { h.UserID} into hh
select new {
    hh.Key.UserID,
    Score = hh.Sum(s => s.Points )
}).OrderByDescending(i => i.Points);
```

**Output**

total: 17

total: 12

Answer (score 0):

Another example with more than one sum and a join

```
 from e in _context.LearnResults
 join c in _context.Country on e.CountryId equals c.CountryId
 where c.DomainId.Equals("xx")
 group e by e.Country.Name into newCountry
 let Approved = newCountry.Sum(e => e.Approved)
 let Total = newCountry.Sum(e => e.Total)
 select new LearnResults() { CountryName = newCountry.Key, Approved= Approved, Total=Total };
```